# When to use setOnClickListener and setChechedChangeListener in android

Tags: android, listener, onclicklistener

I started working with check boxes in android but got confused when to use setCheckedChangelistener and setOnclickListener, pleasae tell me when to select appropriate one and also difference in their implementation.

Comment: Preferable way: `setCheckedChangeListener()` since you can directly use current `CheckBox` value (`isChecked`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClickListener` calls in case, when you click any `View` (`Button`, `TextView`, `EditText` and other). `OnCheckedChangeListener` call when `View` change checked state. It works with `Views` like (`ToggleButton`, `CheckBox`). This `Views` change and store state after click.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

onClickListener is used for widgets like - **Buttons , Textview , EditText , LinearLayout , FrameLayout** , etc.

onCheckedChangeListener is used for compound button widgets like -  **CheckBox, RadioButton, Switch, ToggleButton .**